# Is an attached Record thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jooq, spring-transactions

Is an attached jOOQ `Record` (`UpdatableRecord`) thread-safe, i.e. can I attach (fetch) a Record in one thread, and store it later in another thread without negative effects? Should I detach it in the original thread and attach it back in the new thread?

I know about the jOOQ [manual page](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/thread-safety/) about thread-safety of the `DSLContext`. I'm using the Spring Boot Autoconfiguration of jOOQ, so that should all be thread-safe (with Spring's DataSourceTransactionManager and Hikari pooling).

But the following questions remain:

- How does an attached Record behave when a transaction in the original thread is opened, and `store()` is called in another thread either before or after the original transaction has been committed? Does jOOQ open a new connection every time for each operation?
- Would the attached Record be keeping a connection open across threads, which might then lead to resource leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jOOQ record is not thread safe. It is a simple mutable container backed by an ordinary `Object[]`. As such, all the usual issues may arise when sharing mutable state across threads.

But your question isn't really about the thread safety of the record.

> How does an attached Record behave when a transaction in the original thread is opened, and store() is called in another thread either before or after the original transaction has been committed? Does jOOQ open a new connection every time for each operation?

This has nothing to do with `Record`, but how you configure jOOQ's `ConnectionProvider`. jOOQ doesn't hold a connection or even open one. You do that, explicitly, or implicitly, by passing jOOQ a connection via a `ConnectionProvider` (probably via some Spring configured `DataSource`). jOOQ will, for each database interaction, [`acquire()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#acquire()) a connection, and [`release()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ConnectionProvider.html#release(java.sql.Connection)) it again after the interaction. The `Record` doesn't know how this connection is obtained. It just runs jOOQ queries that acquire and release connections.

In fact, jOOQ doesn't even really care about your transactions (unless you're using jOOQ's transaction API, but you aren't).

> Would the attached Record be keeping a connection open across threads, which might then lead to resource leaks?

No, a Record is "attached" to a `Configuration`, not a connection. That `Configuration` contains a `ConnectionProvider`, which does whatever you configured it to do.